# Crear capa de poligono en google maps api js

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Buenos días, tengo las siguientes coordenadas:

> -90.833910,13.994037 -90.833918,13.994095 -90.833924,13.994152 -90.833930,13.994207 -90.833936,13.994263 -90.833943,13.994322 -90.833951,13.994382 -90.833959,13.994440 -90.833965,13.994494 -90.833971,13.994548 -90.833978,13.994608 -90.833984,13.994671 -90.833993,13.994741 -90.834001,13.994811 -90.834010,13.994877 -90.834019,13.994940 -90.834028,13.995003 -90.834036,13.995060 -90.834044,13.995110 -90.834052,13.995162 -90.834061,13.995222 -90.834067,13.995281 -90.834074,13.995336 -90.834080,13.995390 -90.834086,13.995442 -90.834092,13.995495 -90.834100,13.995553 -90.834105,13.995610 -90.834110,13.995665 -90.834116,13.995718 -90.834122,13.995769 -90.834127,13.995820 -90.834134,13.995871 -90.834141,13.995924 -90.834146,13.995974 -90.834149,13.996008 -90.834192,13.996161 -90.834732,13.996091 -90.835519,13.995989 -90.836038,13.995931 -90.836696,13.995846 -90.836677,13.995819 -90.836660,13.995674 -90.836610,13.995123 -90.836480,13.994146 -90.836461,13.994126 -90.836370,13.994036 -90.836287,13.994044 -90.836194,13.994035 -90.836012,13.993789 -90.836003,13.993753 -90.835995,13.993581 -90.836245,13.993529 -90.836375,13.993521 -90.836386,13.993516 -90.836394,13.993512 -90.836394,13.993503 -90.836395,13.993404 -90.836309,13.992635 -90.836266,13.992318 -90.836207,13.991926 -90.836192,13.991927 -90.836170,13.991932 -90.836125,13.991938 -90.836074,13.991943 -90.836010,13.991951 -90.835936,13.991961 -90.835862,13.991968 -90.835791,13.991976 -90.835722,13.991980 -90.835658,13.991985 -90.835597,13.991994 -90.835533,13.992003 -90.835471,13.992011 -90.835408,13.992018 -90.835346,13.992025 -90.835285,13.992033 -90.835228,13.992040 -90.835173,13.992045 -90.835118,13.992051 -90.835062,13.992057 -90.835002,13.992063 -90.834936,13.992071 -90.834868,13.992078 -90.834800,13.992086 -90.834733,13.992094 -90.834663,13.992102 -90.834588,13.992111 -90.834523,13.992120 -90.834474,13.992123 -90.834421,13.992129 -90.834361,13.992133 -90.834298,13.992140 -90.834229,13.992149 -90.834160,13.992161 -90.834092,13.992171 -90.834022,13.992180 -90.833954,13.992185 -90.833889,13.992191 -90.833824,13.992198 -90.833761,13.992205 -90.833709,13.992212 -90.833680,13.992216 -90.833683,13.992242 -90.833693,13.992300 -90.833704,13.992370 -90.833712,13.992445 -90.833720,13.992518 -90.833727,13.992591 -90.833736,13.992661 -90.833745,13.992730 -90.833755,13.992795 -90.833764,13.992855 -90.833772,13.992913 -90.833779,13.992971 -90.833786,13.993033 -90.833792,13.993092 -90.833799,13.993149 -90.833807,13.993202 -90.833815,13.993251 -90.833823,13.993302 -90.833830,13.993358 -90.833837,13.993410 -90.833843,13.993462 -90.833849,13.993518 -90.833857,13.993579 -90.833864,13.993641 -90.833870,13.993700 -90.833876,13.993760 -90.833881,13.993817 -90.833887,13.993871 -90.833894,13.993927 -90.833902,13.993982 -90.833910,13.994037

Estas coordenadas provienen de un kml y me interesa saber si con ellas puedo dibujar en el mapa un poligono manteniendo el formato actual de las coordenadas, ya que sino se puede tendria que separar miles de coordenadas para utilizar el formato siguiente:

```
var triangleCoords = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];
```

También si fuera posible, como puedo obtener una coordenada central en base a ese grupo de coordenadas?

Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Con la ayuda de Marcos pude crear los poligonos. XD

[image: Poligonos]

---

El código lo tengo de esta manera:

```
    function errores(msg) {
        alert('Error: ' + msg.responseText);
    }

    var bmap;
    function initMaps(flag) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            var myLatLng = { lat: 13.84392970, lng: -90.25855230 };
            var bmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bmap'), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: 'satellite'
            });

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            function addMarker(feature, finca, coordenadas) {
                //inicia crear poligono
                var coords = coordenadas.split(' ') // Separamos por espacio
                        .map(function (data) {
                            var info = data.split(','), // Separamos por coma
                        coord = { // Creamos el obj de coordenada
                            lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
                            lng: parseFloat(info[0])
                        };
                            // Agregamos la coordenada al bounds
                            bounds.extend(coord);
                            return coord;
                        });

                var area = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    paths: coords,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    fillColor: '#BBDEFB',
                    fillOpacity: 0.35
                });

                area.setMap(bmap); // agrega el poligono al mapa
                // finaliza crear poligono

                var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: bounds.getCenter(),
                    map: bmap,
                    title: 'Finca: ' + finca
                });

                //inicia infowindow
                // Add a listener for the click event.
                area.addListener('click', showArrays);
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                // finaliza infowindow
                //------------------------------------
                function showArrays(event) {
                    // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
                    // MVCArray of LatLngs.
                    var vertices = this.getPath();

                    var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
                      'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
                      '<br>';

                    // Iterate over the vertices.
                    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
                        var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
                        contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
                        xy.lng();
                    }

                    // Replace the info window's content and position.
                    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

                    infoWindow.open(bmap);
                }
                //------------------------------------


                bmap.fitBounds(bounds); // ajusta el mapa a la cantidad de marcadores
                //                    //finaliza crear marcador

            } // finaliza addMarker

            var FechaInicial = $('#<%= txtFechaInicial.ClientID %>').val();
            var FechaFinal = $('#<%= txtFechaFinal.ClientID %>').val();
            var Finca = $('#<%= CboFincass.ClientID %>').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "FrmKmlFincas.aspx\/FillMapas",
                data: '{FechaInicial: "' + FechaInicial + '", FechaFinal: "' + FechaFinal + '", Finca: "' + Finca + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                    marcadores = [];
                    finca = [];
                    coordenadas = [];
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        marcadores[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitud, item.Longitud);
                        finca[i] = item.Finca;
                        coordenadas[i] = item.Coordenadas;
                        addMarker(marcadores[i], finca[i], coordenadas[i]); //enviar finca,descricion, etc
                    });
                },
                error: errores
            });
        } else {
            // alert("1");
            var myLatLng = { lat: 14.151171, lng: -90.841083 };
            var bmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bmap'), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: 'satellite'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: bmap,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
        }
    }
```

El problema que tengo, es que el primer marcador que se crea si sale centrado con respecto al poligono, en cambio a partir del segundo ya no. No se si debo limpiar alguna variable. Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> me interesa saber si con ellas puedo dibujar en el mapa un poligono manteniendo el formato actual de las coordenadas

La respuesta es **NO**. Es necesario procesarlas y convertirlas al formato [`LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral) o en un [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng). Lo cual es bastante simple de realizar, solo debemos:

- Separar la `cadena` por un espacio:

  ```
  var params = cadena.split(' ');
  ```
- Por cada valor obtenido, separar por coma y crear el `LatLngLiteral`

  ```
  var coords = params.map(function(data){
    var info = data.split(','),
      coord = {
        lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
        lng: parseFloat(info[0])
      };
    return coord;
  });
  ```

Y listo, ya tenemos la lista de coordenadas procesada.

> como puedo obtener una coordenada central en base a ese grupo de coordenadas?

Lo que podemos hacer es crear un [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) y a medida que procesamos las coordenadas las agregamos al mismo.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var coords = params.map(function(data){
  var info = data.split(','),
    coord = {
      lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
      lng: parseFloat(info[0])
    };
  // Agregamos la coordenada al bounds
  bounds.extend(coord);
  return coord;
});
```

Luego le indicamos al mapa que deseamos centrarlo a las coordenadas centrales del `bounds`

```
// Creamos el mapa
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: bounds.getCenter(), // Centramos el mapa al area
  mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});
```

### Demo

```js
function initMap() {
  // Creamos la instacia bounds
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // Extraemos las coordenadas
  var coords = '-90.833910,13.994037 -90.833918,13.994095 -90.833924,13.994152 -90.833930,13.994207 -90.833936,13.994263 -90.833943,13.994322 -90.833951,13.994382 -90.833959,13.994440 -90.833965,13.994494 -90.833971,13.994548 -90.833978,13.994608 -90.833984,13.994671 -90.833993,13.994741 -90.834001,13.994811 -90.834010,13.994877 -90.834019,13.994940 -90.834028,13.995003 -90.834036,13.995060 -90.834044,13.995110 -90.834052,13.995162 -90.834061,13.995222 -90.834067,13.995281 -90.834074,13.995336 -90.834080,13.995390 -90.834086,13.995442 -90.834092,13.995495 -90.834100,13.995553 -90.834105,13.995610 -90.834110,13.995665 -90.834116,13.995718 -90.834122,13.995769 -90.834127,13.995820 -90.834134,13.995871 -90.834141,13.995924 -90.834146,13.995974 -90.834149,13.996008 -90.834192,13.996161 -90.834732,13.996091 -90.835519,13.995989 -90.836038,13.995931 -90.836696,13.995846 -90.836677,13.995819 -90.836660,13.995674 -90.836610,13.995123 -90.836480,13.994146 -90.836461,13.994126 -90.836370,13.994036 -90.836287,13.994044 -90.836194,13.994035 -90.836012,13.993789 -90.836003,13.993753 -90.835995,13.993581 -90.836245,13.993529 -90.836375,13.993521 -90.836386,13.993516 -90.836394,13.993512 -90.836394,13.993503 -90.836395,13.993404 -90.836309,13.992635 -90.836266,13.992318 -90.836207,13.991926 -90.836192,13.991927 -90.836170,13.991932 -90.836125,13.991938 -90.836074,13.991943 -90.836010,13.991951 -90.835936,13.991961 -90.835862,13.991968 -90.835791,13.991976 -90.835722,13.991980 -90.835658,13.991985 -90.835597,13.991994 -90.835533,13.992003 -90.835471,13.992011 -90.835408,13.992018 -90.835346,13.992025 -90.835285,13.992033 -90.835228,13.992040 -90.835173,13.992045 -90.835118,13.992051 -90.835062,13.992057 -90.835002,13.992063 -90.834936,13.992071 -90.834868,13.992078 -90.834800,13.992086 -90.834733,13.992094 -90.834663,13.992102 -90.834588,13.992111 -90.834523,13.992120 -90.834474,13.992123 -90.834421,13.992129 -90.834361,13.992133 -90.834298,13.992140 -90.834229,13.992149 -90.834160,13.992161 -90.834092,13.992171 -90.834022,13.992180 -90.833954,13.992185 -90.833889,13.992191 -90.833824,13.992198 -90.833761,13.992205 -90.833709,13.992212 -90.833680,13.992216 -90.833683,13.992242 -90.833693,13.992300 -90.833704,13.992370 -90.833712,13.992445 -90.833720,13.992518 -90.833727,13.992591 -90.833736,13.992661 -90.833745,13.992730 -90.833755,13.992795 -90.833764,13.992855 -90.833772,13.992913 -90.833779,13.992971 -90.833786,13.993033 -90.833792,13.993092 -90.833799,13.993149 -90.833807,13.993202 -90.833815,13.993251 -90.833823,13.993302 -90.833830,13.993358 -90.833837,13.993410 -90.833843,13.993462 -90.833849,13.993518 -90.833857,13.993579 -90.833864,13.993641 -90.833870,13.993700 -90.833876,13.993760 -90.833881,13.993817 -90.833887,13.993871 -90.833894,13.993927 -90.833902,13.993982 -90.833910,13.994037'
    .split(' ') // Separamos por espacio
    .map(function(data) {
      var info = data.split(','), // Separamos por coma
        coord = { // Creamos el obj de coordenada
          lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
          lng: parseFloat(info[0])
        };
      // Agregamos la coordenada al bounds
      bounds.extend(coord);
      return coord;
    });


  // Creamos el poligono
  var area = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  // Creamos el mapa
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: bounds.getCenter(), // Centramos el mapa al area
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Agregamos el area al mapa
  area.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCK3ulYYM8GCwK-_HlZVNKvkgp-zvEebUM&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu genial ayuda Marcos, muy agradecido.

Comment: Ahora bien, si grabo un marcador en cada poligono que se creó, como puedo obtener el area central para grabarlo? Gracias.

Comment: @raintrooper, ¿quisieras obtener el area central al grupo de marcadores?, si es esa la pregunta, una solución es exactamente la misma que para los polígonos.

Comment: @Marcos una pregunta! Me interesa la solución que propones para armar un polígono específico con coordenadas. Lo que yo necesito es que, dentro de un campo de formulario en html, donde tengo implementado el autocomplete de google maps, se valide que la dirección esté dentro del polígono, y si no lo está que salte un mensaje de error. Espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: @Marcos PD: no me hace falta mostrar el mapa en mi caso, es simplemente escribir dirección y validar que esté dentro del polígono

Comment: @DamianRicobelli, te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta así puedes obtener la respuesta. Así mismo te dejo [este enlace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) a modo de pista ;)

Comment: @Marcos dale, gracias! Ahora mismo creo la respuesta

Comment: @Marcos Ahí fue creada! :D Con el título de "Validar que una dirección esté contenida en un área de mapa con API Google Maps"